# C# Methods not being called in switch statement?

Tags: c#, methods

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Menu_Attempts
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            bool forever = true;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1. Stone to Pounds");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Quit");

                int reply = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (reply)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount in Stone");
                        double UserInput = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        StoneToPounds(UserInput);

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("You've decided to quit.");
                        forever = false;

                        break;

                }
            } while (forever);

        }

        public static double StoneToPounds(double number)
        {
            double answer = number * 14;
            return answer;
        }

    }
}
```

So I'm trying to make a console based menu, and calling methods when needed to clean it up. I select option 1. to convert stone to pounds and it gives me the option to input a number. But when I do it simply loops back to the begging of the menu?

Comment: You never output/write the result of StoneToPounds() ...

Comment: you aren't doing anything with the return value of `StoneToPounds`. It will be getting called, you just don't see any output from it, your do while loop is then starting again as expected

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(StoneToPounds(UserInput));` ?

Comment: If you want to stop the loop after conversion, set forever to false after the StoneToPounds call.

Comment: You are not toggling 'forever' Boolean variable and that's why while loop continue to execute again. I just don't understand is that why you are using while loop if you are simply making conversion program. You can just use switch...case control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your method is being called (and you can prove that by adding a breakpoint), but you're not actually doing anything with the `StoneToPounds` method result. Maybe you can do something like this:

```
case 1:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount in Stone");
    double UserInput = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("The result is {0}", StoneToPounds(UserInput));
    break;
```

You'll see, soon enough, that you code will break whenever the user enters a text or anything different than a number; I would suggest to take a look into [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

The methods are fine. You are just not printing the answer. Change your code like this to print the answer:

```
case 1:
   Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount in Stone");
   double UserInput = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   double result = StoneToPounds(UserInput);
   Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

   break;
```

Comment: Yup just noticed that, your answer is much better than how I fixed it to. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add this line of code just before you call `break`:

```
Console.WriteLine("The result is {0}", StoneToPounds(UserInput));
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

as others said ... you method is called and returning the double value ...but you are not saving it any kind of variables , if u wan't ur method to operate on the variable itself you can pass it as a ref parameter this way any change happens to the variable inside ur method will affect the variable globally

```
public static void StoneToPounds(ref double number)
    {
        number *= 14
    }
```

btw the operator *= could eliminate ur need for a separate function , if u r a beginner then you should now that less code is always better as long as u can keep it clean and organized :D

Comment: The method already returns the value, there's no need to complicate things by adding `ref` here.

Comment: the purpose of the answer is to share knowledge and enlighten him that C# has such an option in case he needed it some day , technically there is no need for method at all ..but the dude is still learning we should try to help him as long as the information related to same topic and not advanced level

Comment: @RubensFarias you only quoted half of my words ,,,as long as it's clean and organized and it dosn't have a negative impact on performance then less code is better ,less code with bad performance or at the cost of readability is not good at all